# High Sleep Power Consumption in Yosemite

Tags: macos, sleep, power-management

Over the last week, my OS X Yosemite (rMBP 2015) has been consuming large amounts of power in sleep mode (~20% over 12 hours). I am not aware of any particular thing I might have done to make this happen - and neither is activity monitor showing any unusual process in the energy tab. Until now - the sleep consumption would be such that I would lose about 2-3% battery for every 12 hours - so its almost 10-times now.

What could the possible problems and solution be?

[image: High Sleep Power Consumtion]

Answer (score -1):

The only thing you could really do is see if Yosemite has features similar to the Intel Smart Connect tech, where the OS will wake and effectively refresh itself, and allow email and such to update. Looking in Activity Monitor would be something to consider.

If Yosemite does indeed have a feature similar to the Intel Smart Connect tech, then it is also possible that the MacBook isn't falling asleep again for an hour or so, while it updates email, refreshes pages, and does other things.

Other than that, OS X **should not** be wasting that much power, as it should be quite efficient at doing things.